# There is a blank colomn in my photo gallery

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am kinda new and still learning, but today I downloaded a template to get myself started and when I changed the images there is suddenly a blank column: https://gyazo.com/a62f5e3de25876c9262d9894cc7d39f3 <--- see picture.

I have tried changing the columns around as well as changing the md-4 to like md-3.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 work">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/Schorisse 201204-11.jpg" alt="oops"">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="work-content">
                    <span>De kinderen</span>
                    <h3>(Lekker) samen op de trampoline</h3>
                    <div class="work-link">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
                        <a class="lightbox" href="img/Schorisse 201204-11.jpg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 work">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/3Z2A3280 (1).jpg" alt="oops">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="work-content">
                    <span>Trouwfeest</span>
                    <h3>Piet</h3>
                    <div class="work-link">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
                        <a class="lightbox" href="img/3Z2A3280 (1).jpg" alt="oops"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 work">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/059.jpg" alt="oops">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="work-content">
                    <span>Gezinfototjes</span>
                    <h3>En wat zien ze er gelukkig uit!</h3>
                    <div class="work-link">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
                        <a class="lightbox" href="img/IMG-20170408-WA0012.jpg" alt="oops">    ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            

                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 work">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/021.jpg" alt="oops">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="work-content">
                    <span>Trippy en Bomma</span>
                    <h3>Beetje gek doen!</h3>
                    <div class="work-link">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
                        <a class="lightbox" href="img/021.jpg" alt="oops"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


                
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 work">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/IMG_4028.JPG" alt="oops">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="work-content">
                    <span>De bomma en bompa</span>
                    <h3>Ruik ik daar bier?!</h3>
                    <div class="work-link">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
                        <a class="lightbox" href="img/IMG_4028.JPG" alt="oops"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            

            
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 work">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/IMG-20160220-WA0004.jpg" alt="oops">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="work-content">
                    <span>Gezinfototjes</span>
                    <h3>En wat zien ze er gelukkig uit!!</h3>
                    <div class="work-link">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
                        <a class="lightbox" href="img/IMG-20160220-WA0004.jpg" alt="oops"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /Work -->

        </div>
        <!-- /Row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /Container -->

</div>
```

I expect the problem is between image 3 and 4 but I am not sure.

Comment: This is happening because of the float that bootstrap applies to the columns. The first picture is slightly bigger than the next ones so when you get to the next row - the fourth image is positioned where it is due to the height of the first image. To fix this - either a) make the images the same height or b)  put each group of three images into separate rows (ie: within a div.row) and each row will be as tall as the largest image.

Comment: you should not have alt="oops"" but rather alt="oops"  in your second row ;)
moreover, you should put three images into one row, then 3 images into the next row. 
If you want some more flexibility, try to use flexbox: https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use `flexbox` with the option `flex-wrap: wrap`, but that may break your Bootstrap grid (looks like Bootstrap).

Another solution would be to use a JavaScript plugin like Masonry (https://masonry.desandro.com/), this will calculate the position of each photo and create a nice grid.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have columns outside of rows in bootstrap:

every

```
<div class="col-*">
```

should always be wrapped by a `<div class="row">`

like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-*"></div>
   <div class="col-*"></div>
</div
```